Inverse participation ratio for random matrices
I was trying to derive certain results related to the Inverse participation ratio for the case of GOE and GUE random matrices. Apparently the result is already given elsewhere. However, it is written in an "obvious" manner and I could not derive it no matter what. To briefly describe the problem the IPR for a state $\psi$ is given by $$IPR= \sum_{a}|\langle a|\psi\rangle|^{4}$$, where $|a\rangle$ are the eigenstates of a given Hamiltonian $H$. Now to obtain the RMT results you can do an ensemble average, assuming the results are independent of the choice of $\psi$. For the case of complex eigenstates $|a\rangle$ , the case of GUE, the qunatity $\langle a|\psi\rangle$ can be thought of as a random complex variable and one obtains $$N \times IPR = 2N/(N+1)$$.
The above results is what is given in the paper, in page 2. Based on what is given I assumed that $|\langle a|\psi\rangle| = A+ i B$ is some complex random complex number with A and B chosen at random. Then $|\langle a|\psi\rangle|^{4} = A^{4}+ 2 A^{2} B^{2} + B^{4}$. I was trying to substitute this value in the summmation for $IPR$ and then try to use some properties of $A$ and $B$ being random. However, I could not proceed any further as I do not have any idea of what further property of random variable I can use to obtain the average value. Is this the correct way to approach the problem? Or I am doing something wrong. For the reference I have attached the paper and the result is stated in page 2, in the first paragraph itself.
More info: After thinking about it a bit more, I think one can have a bit more information. So the normalization implies $\sum_{a} |\langle a|\psi\rangle|^{2}= 1$, hence we can think of $|\langle a|\psi\rangle|^{2} \sim x_{i}$, such that the $\sum_{i} x_{i} = 1$ ($x_{i}$ is some real number which can now be thought of as being chosen uniformly from the interval [0,1]) and now we are interested in finding the average value of $\sum_{i} x_{i}^{2}$ which may be thought of as the moment of the distribution described by $x_{i}$. Though I am still unable to understand how this distribution changes depending on whether $|\langle a|\psi\rangle|$ is real or complex and how does one can find its value.
Further thought : I think I have figured out what I exactly need now. With a little bit more thought on this I have figured out that the problem is to simply figure out some moments of uniformly distributed points on a real or complex sphere and it will do the job.
